# Using different ciphers with paramiko

Tags: python, paramiko

How can  I specify a different cipher to be used on a paramiko ssh/sftp connection? (similar to -c command line from scp/ssh).

I have tried the following code:

```
    self.sshclient = paramiko.SSHClient()
    self.sshclient.load_system_host_keys()
    self.sshclient.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    self.sshclient.connect(hostname, **ssh_kwargs)

    self.transport = self.sshclient.get_transport()
    self.transport.get_security_options().ciphers = ('arcfour128',)
    self.transport.set_keepalive(keepalive)

    self.channel = self.transport.open_session()                                                                                                     
    self.channel.settimeout(timeout)
```

But on debug I could see:

```
2016/02/26 15:27:47 DEBUG   Ciphers agreed: local=aes128-ctr, remote=aes128-ctr
2016/02/26 15:27:47 DEBUG   using kex diffie-hellman-group1-sha1; server key type ssh-rsa; cipher: local aes128-ctr, remote aes128-ctr; mac: local hmac-sha1, remote hmac-sha1; compression: local none, remote none
```

I have read somewhere that Connect should happen after the `get_security_options()`, inverting that causes me `self.transport` be of `NoneType` (seems transport is related with a connection).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with the SSHClient is that the session is started during `connect()` and according to [Transport docs](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/1.16/api/transport.html?highlight=cipher#paramiko.transport.SecurityOptions):

> Changing the contents and/or order of these fields affects the underlying Transport (but only if you change them before starting the session).

What you can do is override `Transport`'s preferred ciphers:

```
paramiko.Transport._preferred_ciphers = ('arcfour128', )
self.sshclient = paramiko.SSHClient()
self.sshclient.load_system_host_keys()
self.sshclient.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
self.sshclient.connect(hostname, **ssh_kwargs)
...
```

If what you want is only an SFTP connection, you can create a `Transport` first and create the `SFTPClient` object from that transport:

```
self.transport = paramiko.Transport((hostname, 22))
self.transport.get_security_options().ciphers = ('arcfour128', )
self.transport.connect(username=user, password=pass)  # or pkeys, ...
self.transport.set_keepalive(keepalive)
self.sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(self.transport)
self.sftp.put('local_file', 'remote_path')
self.sftp.close()
```